# Getting an error when running React with asp.net core and getting data from controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am running a tutorial from reactjs.net. When I get to the part that gets the data from the controller instead of from the page (which works), it gets an error.

I put a breakpoint on the controller for the method for the route "comments" and it never gets there. I assume the "url" is having a problem.

The page looks like:

[image]

The controller page looks like:

[image]

The error I get it:

[image]

Comment: Where is react router in your project ?

Comment: Not sure. This is not the normal Reactjs, apparently. This is run out of Visual Studio and is an MVC project with Reactjs as the front end. The tutorial is on Reacjs.com. Seemed to work fine until I got to this part. The url is: https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html